# iPhone html5 video avoid native fullscreen when using airplay on Safari

Tags: iphone, html, video, mobile-safari, airplay

I know that allowsInlineMediaPlayback only works on iPad, but my goal is to play the video on AppleTV, while I am displaying some dynamic html content on Safari. I basically want to get rid of the airplay indicator screen or hide it somehow, or open a new tab while the video keeps playing or kind of minimize it display just a small pause button on the bottom of my html page while the video is playing on AppleTV.

If this is not possible to be done on iPhone, can it be done on iPad ? I want to have as much space as possible on the safari page and just a pause button for the video.